# How to test springboot with from an android emulator app

Tags: java, android, spring, android-volley

I am working on an android project which I used springboot for the webservice. It the any possible way of testing the spring boot project before deployment. What I mean is-*how can I run the spring boot project and and make the app from the emulator to work with it*.
I'm using volley for the http client request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ip adress of pc where spring boot app turn (**ex :** http://192.168.100.100:port) as base url for volley request.

The two device must be connected to the same access point(WI-FI).

Comment: For connection on localhost I think that Android use ```10.0.0.2``` instead of the IP address of your machine.